# How to convert String to Timestamp in kafka connect using transforms and insert into postgres using jdbc sink connector from confluent?

Tags: schema, apache-kafka-connect, jdbctemplate, confluent-platform

Below is my kafka-connect-sink.properties file
I am using confluent-6.0.1.

```
name=enba-sink-postgres
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector
connection.url=jdbc:postgresql://IP:PORT/DB
connection.user=USERNAME
connection.password=PASSWORD
tasks.max=1
topics=postgresInsert
insert.mode=INSERT
table.name.format=schema."tableName"
auto.create=false
key.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081 
key.converter.schemas.enable=false
value.converter.schemas.enable=false
config.action.reload=restart
value.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081 
errors.tolerance=all 
errors.log.enable=true
errors.log.include.messages=true
print.key=true 
    
# Transforms
transforms=TimestampConverter
transforms.TimestampConverter.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.TimestampConverter$Value
transforms.TimestampConverter.format=yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
transforms.TimestampConverter.target.type=Timestamp
transforms.TimestampConverter.target.field=DATE_TIME
```

I am using avro data and schema is :

```
 {\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"log\",\"namespace\":\"transform.name.space\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"TRANSACTION_ID\",\"type\":{\"type\":\"string\",\"avro.java.string\":\"String\"},\"avro.java.string\":\"String\"},{\"name\":\"MSISDN\",\"type\":{\"type\":\"string\",\"avro.java.string\":\"String\"},\"avro.java.string\":\"String\"},{\"name\":\"TRIGGER_NAME\",\"type\":{\"type\":\"string\",\"avro.java.string\":\"String\"},\"avro.java.string\":\"String\"},{\"name\":\"W_ID\",\"type\":{\"type\":\"string\",\"avro.java.string\":\"String\"},\"avro.java.string\":\"String\"},{\"name\":\"STEP\",\"type\":{\"type\":\"string\",\"avro.java.string\":\"String\"},\"avro.java.string\":\"String\"},{\"name\":\"REWARD_ID\",\"type\":{\"type\":\"string\",\"avro.java.string\":\"String\"},\"avro.java.string\":\"String\"},{\"name\":\"CAM_ID\",\"type\":{\"type\":\"string\",\"avro.java.string\":\"String\"},\"avro.java.string\":\"String\"},{\"name\":\"STATUS\",\"type\":{\"type\":\"string\",\"avro.java.string\":\"String\"},\"avro.java.string\":\"String\"},{\"name\":\"COMMENTS\",\"type\":{\"type\":\"string\",\"avro.java.string\":\"String\"},\"avro.java.string\":\"String\"},{\"name\":\"CCR_JSON\",\"type\":{\"type\":\"string\",\"avro.java.string\":\"String\"},\"avro.java.string\":\"String\"},{\"name\":\"DATE_TIME\",\"type\":{\"type\":\"string\",\"avro.java.string\":\"String\"},\"avro.java.string\":\"String\"}]}
```

Basically DATE_TIME column in Postgres is of type Timestamp and from avro I tried sending String date and also of type long .
DATE_TIME = 2022-12-15 14:38:02

Issue is If I dont use transform then I am getting error :

```
ERROR: column "DATE_TIME" is of type timestamp with time zone but expression is of type character varying
```

And If I use transforms as mentioned above then error is :

```
    [2021-02-06 21:47:41,897] ERROR Error encountered in task enba-sink-postgres-0. Executing stage 'TRANSFORMATION' with class 'org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.TimestampConverter$Value', where consumed record is {topic='enba', partition=0, offset=69, timestamp=1612628261605, timestampType=CreateTime}. (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.LogReporter:66)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Schema Schema{com.package.kafkaconnect.Enbalog:STRUCT} does not correspond to a known timestamp type format
```

Comment: Does it with with `DATE_TIME` as a string and quotation marks around the `format` i.e.: `transforms.TimestampConverter.format="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"`

Comment: No this does not work , I had tried it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working using :

```
 # Transforms
transforms= timestamp
transforms.timestamp.type= org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.TimestampConverter$Value
transforms.timestamp.target.type= Timestamp
transforms.timestamp.field= DATE_TIME
transforms.timestamp.format= yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
```

For some reason transforms=TimestampConverter was not working.

Comment: This saved me. I was wondering how to do this. I have a kafka stream that is sending a timestamp but it is a string. I needed the to sink that data with a JDBC sink connector so I needed to change the time stamp to a timestamp type. Thanks a million

Comment: Did someone try this on a Sink of Confluent Platform v7.3.2?